# How can I clear the symbol \[ImaginaryJ] for use for another purpose?

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols

By default it is the same as imaginary unit, but I want to use it for split-complex numbers.

Comment: Probably best to use `\[DoubleStruckJ]` instead.

Comment: @QuantumDot Good idea! But it does not exist on the palette...

Comment: @QuantumDot also when copied into latex, it gives thick j, as in a vector: $\frac{i \pi }{2}-\frac{i \pi  \mathbf{j}}{2}$.

Comment: You might try altering the `Format` of whatever you are wanting to show as the imaginary j.

Comment: Also look up : `Unprotect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot clear it, because `\[ImaginaryJ]` does not have a definition. `\[ImaginaryJ]` does not transform to `I` through the normal evaluation procedure. Instead, it is directly *parsed* as the imaginary unit.

You can see this by evaluating

```
ToExpression["\[ImaginaryJ]", InputForm, HoldComplete]
```

The result will be `HoldComplete[I]`, not `HoldComplete[\[ImageinaryJ]]`.